# Engine is slightly more noisy after rear seal replacement

Tags: noise

I got a real seal replacement on my car which is an automatic transmission. After the repair, the engine is slightly more noisy and the noise has a slightly higher pitch.

Is this normal? What could have caused the change?

Note that to do this repair the engine has to be taken off its mounts to drop the transmission out. However, my understanding is that remounting the engine should not make any difference to how the engine runs, even if the remounting is off in some way. Is that not the case?

In other words, could there be some kind of alignment issue? My mechanic said that the engine does not need to be re-aligned in any way.

Comment: Missing alignment of engine and transmission?

Comment: please provide make, year, model, of car. I have 45 years exp and my Son now has 10, if I can't answer, He can. hopefully.

Comment: Did they change the fluid

Comment: Is there oil in the engine?

Comment: Mechanic is incompetent if he will not help you solve the issue, it is clear the problem was caused by his repair from what I have read. Yes I have have made mistakes and never gave lame excuses, but always fixed them for the customer at no cost.

Comment: Diagnosing noises on this site is a ridiculous idea. We need to know if the work was done in the first place because of the sounds the OP was hearing.  A "slight higher pitch" is subjective. What the OP thinks is a concerning sound may not be to anyone else. If the sound was there before doesn't necessarily mean the mechanic did anything wrong. IMO, the source of the sound needs to be found. That will tell you what is going on more than us guessing.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes, it got a complete oil change during the repair. The noise change does sound exactly like that though, the car running low on oil.

Comment: Just one of those stupid questions I had to ask. :o)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no fluids etc have been drained or lost anywhere... Sometimes when an engine/gearbox is lifted or disturbed in some way as in this case here, the engine/gearbox can be very slightly misaligned or rather not sitting exactly the way it was before, so there can be slightly different loadings on the main supports when everything is reassembled.

This is not normally an issue however there can be pipes/cables/wires etc which can sometimes become trapped or have just been moved into a position where they weren't before, or they maybe rubbing or be in contact with the body in some way due to the very slightly strained way things have been re-secured. If there is any wiring or cabling contacting the body where it wasn't previously this can transfer any engine sounds back into the vehicle and amplify them, giving you the impression that something is sounds wrong or different.

In this case I would have the garage that did the work double check it. Just indicate to them that you feel that something sounds incorrect since the work was carried out. Explain if you can what sounds different.. It may help guide the mechanics to the issue.